# How to declare type for an array holding objects of type derived of the methods of a class?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a Contract class which holds the contract for a function:

```
    type MethodType = (...args: any) => any;
    class Contract<T extends MethodType> {

    }
```

I want to have a similar class for classes. My try to achieve it:

```
    class ContractForClass<T extends Record<string, any>> {
        methods!: Record<string, Contract<MethodType>;

        forMethod(methodName: string): Contract<MethodType> {
            return this.methods[methodName]
        }
        setContractForMethod(method: string, contract: Contract<MethodType>) {
            this.methods[method] = contract
        }

    }
```

My problem is that type information is lost for the method contract. In the example below the retrieved contracts do not have their original type:

```
    const classContract = new ContractForClass<HttpClient<number>>();
    classContract.setContractForMethod("get", new Contract<HttpClient<number>["get"]>)
    classContract.setContractForMethod("post", new Contract<HttpClient<number>["post"]>)


    const getcontract = classContract.forMethod("get")//want Contract<(url: string) => number >
    const postContract = classContract.forMethod("post")//want Contract<(url:string, payload: number) => void>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwGwQwZx4ASAXJAHAwhAlgUwHZIA8AKgHzADeAUKLcAOY5IAUArgE4QBcwMS7WPPQCUXYpRp0p7JhzzA8rCBGCxgxSVIC%20VTXVQB7Pm05c%20AoQBpgqKAE8IBqABMexYRL20d33bSR2qDjAALJMABYGzsSBwQC8wMwAdClQ7PQwPFB4dh5x5Nl2ANx6kLDw6AYE7FBgROI4AB5I%20M7wYUiR0bHk1Ho6pdBwwJXVtUgAYgbsmOUkwE0teG3AAEo4YNPOhOaC9NaFpL1eoAC2EVEwAIQ865vs27tWI1X844QdXTFBpCUnIAAzaafKLMc6dKIAOSg5x4TxEPFGbzqHwu3R%20Eik0lk7HknSwMCS4K6MAA2sSoTCcABdf7AHxYmBMJE1OpTdgg5xgtFw-h7aybMZ1RGvVlETnfHCkDzULF0fGEiltclo6nABKC5FIOkDXylKp8cBDGAs8bqhQ4ADuLyFk2mszghGQaEwuAIhEUpwARjh2EdmMISrQynBTXUkkykGG7Ry0cwAESMJDx6x4K02rVOlAYbD4Iien1%200mJpjx6nSwblaMR5mi8bszkJwx8FMW63RrMu3Pugu%200jF5vJ8vCXT6vCGpOasXmkMmuvhoGxiFckvJ4QAenXluySAzYsIJm4vD5Qjy5F77GApDHhsH0Znxuri8b8cH8Y3W53e-eh7MJ-2Nj2I4Lg8BeZ7AAAbgYWDONetC6EAA)

Answer (score 0):

The key was using mapped type and generic type for the functions.

There is still a problem, allowing setting contract for other method than intended, but it is a matter of another question.

```
    type MethodType = (...args: any) => any;

    class Contract<T extends MethodType> {

    }

    type Methods<T> = {
        [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends MethodType ? Key : never;
    }[keyof T];

    type ContractsFor<T> = { [K in Methods<T>]: T[K] extends MethodType ? Contract<T[K]> : never }


    class ContractForClass<T extends Record<string, any>> {

        methods!: ContractsFor<T>;

        forMethod<K extends Methods<T>>(methodName: K): Contract<T[K]> {
            return this.methods[methodName]
        }

        setContractForMethod<K extends Methods<T>>(method: K, contract: ContractsFor<T>[K]): void {
            this.methods[method] = contract
        }

    }

    class MyHttpClient<T> {
        a: string = "hello"
        get(url: string): T {
            return null as T
        }

        post(url: string, payload: T) {

        }
    }

    const classContract = new ContractForClass<MyHttpClient<number>>();
    classContract.setContractForMethod("get", new Contract<MyHttpClient<number>["get"]>)
    classContract.setContractForMethod("post", new Contract<MyHttpClient<number>["post"]>)
    classContract.setContractForMethod("post", new Contract<MyHttpClient<number>["get"]>)//should be a type error

    const getcontract = classContract.forMethod("get")//got Contract<(url: string) => number >
    const postContract = classContract.forMethod("post")//got Contract<(url:string, payload: number) => void>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BZGYAWB7AJgFWnAvMACgDoSBDAJwHMBnALmFIDsIBKYXAPgeYG4AoPqGABjADalq1YAGFUjMOVLCwAHkzAYADzAxG6KYhQZssLgG8BQgL6XQkWAiRp9arvgtChAbQDSMCMAAlozAANb+qABmwJgAuvSYvv6xGtq6+o5GWDjAAPzAfgH0jDAAbjDk-NZe4RBRMbH8gnY5svKKytQAYqjkruzAZsC+QSGGztSu8TG+KVo6egZOxjn5bQpKqok+sVzFZRXANrYgYhJS6x1gPeTS4pJqqQsZAEowwr3oKtQKwZQANNwIBxzCdPABbZb6ACE9Eum26vVcTU8oEivXGGBUPie6SWWUmmBBBEhWQAcqRIfQfCw4XINso1LNQajUeQkABXcghFCBahEUkTLyCjAUyGxZqo46s4DUJDw5Q3TFfHHzPGZCauDgkqHUwEfdqbOmGzo3VyzWnAUqoQLoQaSmXgZB8gVQ6jCqEpfAGhlgB3WMHS0BnSQICAACTAYCgd0Cui2LNZpHoP3IfwGACJkDBRKJUBn-aBKEgCFzRCnfoxKJb1B5HSB2WAuSFGBzcwwpJhCyAg6ioKgfqXyOXZZWAcAoKQIHnSOgEmwLN2jg7eyI5D8RPdqAqwAMSgB3GT0q43O7nFTwCNRmOiOPyFSt8EAIwqxJYVWDW53RDlYB3SqhAgM2LMAM0BA8jxNVRL0jaNY3jB8OWfV8vGApAM12FgHRDbdj02H95TwxUMUAjN+x+MDgAgncLyvODbwQx8X3IDhUPI0DMOwr8iLAAi-x4gCsiA9jKOonjaNgm871UJiULQjiOBYAB6JTqDQNs7RfBhwByCpyF6MEDQ3ECfSuAYcO-dFyGVICQIzZSlMoVBdxoocR1TP42E4KikOY4AOGw9dd3YndzO4qCiCsmyyIHUCHKclzxLc2gPKrQFJ2nVBZ2KXyKi8rhrVtAKgA)